# Inserting value in DataTable tp mysql database in using ajax/php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I need help in inserting the value of a datatable to mysql I used ajax and php here is my code

```
<?php   
    $query="SELECT products_code,brand_name,products_name,category_name,subcategory_name,supplier_company,products_status,products_acquisitionprice,products_sellingprice,products_ceiling,products_reorderpoint,products_flooring,products_quantity FROM tblproduct,tblsubcategory,tblcategory,tblsupplier,tblbrand WHERE tblcategory.category_id=tblproduct.category_id && tblsubcategory.subcategory_id=tblproduct.subcategory_id && tblsupplier.supplier_id=tblproduct.supplier_id && tblbrand.brand_id=tblproduct.brand_id   order by products_name";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);

?>
<div class="table-responsive container-fluid">
  <table id="product_data" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Product ID</td>
        <td>Product Name</td>
        <td>Product Brand</td>
        <td>Product Category</td>
        <td>Product Sub-Category</td>
        <td>Product Supplier</td>
        <td>Product Status</td>
        <td>Product Acquisition Price</td>
        <td>Product Ceiling</td>
        <td>Product Re-order Point</td>
        <td>Product Flooring</td>
        <td>Product Stock</td>
        <td>Order On Queue</td>
        <td>Total Order Cost</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php
    $tablecount=0;
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      $ooq=$row['products_ceiling']-$row['products_quantity'];
      $totalcost=$row['products_acquisitionprice']*$ooq;
      ?>
      <tr>
        <td class="products_code">  <?php echo$row['products_code']?>  </td>
        <td class="products_name">  <?php echo$row['products_name']?>  </td>
        <td class="brand_name">  <?php echo$row['brand_name']?>  </td>
        <td class="category_name">  <?php echo$row['category_name']?>  </td>
        <td class="subcategory_name">  <?php echo$row['subcategory_name']?>  </td>
        <td class="supplier_company">  <?php echo$row['supplier_company']?>  </td>
        <td class="products_status">  <?php echo$row['products_status']?>  </td>
        <td class="products_acquisitionprice">  <?php echo$row['products_acquisitionprice']?>  </td>
        <td class="products_ceiling">  <?php echo$row['products_ceiling']?>  </td>
        <td class="products_reorderpoint">  <?php echo$row['products_reorderpoint']?>  </td>
        <td class="products_flooring">  <?php echo$row['products_flooring']?>  </td>
        <td class="products_quantity">  <?php echo$row['products_quantity']?>  </td>
        <td class="ooq">  <?php echo$ooq?>  </td>
        <td class="totalcost">  <?php echo$totalcost?>  </td>
      </tr>
      <?php

      $tablecount++;
    }
    ?>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="card-footer">
  <button type="button"  class="btn btn-info btn-sm" name="Order" id="Order"  style="background-color: green;">
   Order Itemss
 </button>
 <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" style="background-color: maroon;">
   Clear
 </button>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){


 $('#Order').click(function(){
  var products_code = [];
  var supplier_company = [];
  var ooq = [];
  var totalcost = [];
  $('.products_code').each(function(){
   products_code.push($(this).text());
  });`enter code here`
  $('.supplier_company').each(function(){
   supplier_company.push($(this).text());
  });
  $('.ooq').each(function(){
   ooq.push($(this).text());
  });
  $('.totalcost').each(function(){
   totalcost.push($(this).text());
  });
  $.ajax({
   url:"Order.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{products_code:products_code, supplier_company:supplier_company, ooq:ooq, totalcost:totalcost},
   success:function(data){
    alert(data);
    $("td[contentEditable='true']").text("");
    for(var i=2; i<= count; i++)
    {
     $('tr#'+i+'').remove();
    }
    fetch_item_data();
   }
  });
 }); 
});
</script>
```

and here is my php:

```
<?php
    //insert.php
    include('session.php');
    if(isset($_POST["products_code"]))
    {
        $products_code = $_POST["products_code"];
        $supplier_company = $_POST["supplier_company"];
        $ooq = $_POST["ooq"];
        $totalcost = $_POST["totalcost"];
        $sql = '';
        for($count = 0; $count<count($products_code); $count++)
        {
            $products_code_clean = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $products_code[$count]);
            $supplier_company_clean = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $supplier_company[$count]);
            $ooq_clean = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $ooq[$count]);
            $totalcost_clean = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $totalcost[$count]);
            if($products_code_clean != '' && $supplier_company_clean != '' && $totalcost_clean != '' && $ooq_clean != '')
            {
                $sql.="INSERT INTO tblorder VALUES(DEFAULT,$products_code_clean,$ooq_clean,(SELECT supplier_id from tblsupplier where supplier_company='$supplier_company_clean'),now(),$totalcost_clean,'Pending Arrival')";
            }
        }
        if($sql != '')
        {
            if(mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql))
            {
                echo 'Item Data Inserted';
            }
            else
            {
                $error="";
                echo $conn->$error;
                echo $products_code_clean;
                echo $ooq_clean;
                echo $supplier_company_clean;
                echo $totalcost_clean;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'All Fields are Required';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please include what your concrete problem is / a possible error message / what you have tried to debug so far. It's otherwise hard to scan the provided code and guess every possible issue.

Comment: nvm i solved it the error was foreign key related issues because my  <td class="supplier_company">  <?php echo$row['supplier_company']?>  </td> has spaces between it. All i had to do was remove the spaces and it worked.